# Get a list from a dynamic json result

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

using

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
```

I get the following Json

```
{
 facet_counts: {
  facet_queries: { },
   facet_fields: {
     Suggest: [
      "AAA",
      0,
      "BBB",
      0,
      "CCC",
      0,
      "DDD",
      0,
      "EEE",
      0]
},
```

I want to iterate "Suggest" get a list of the values in odds location (1,3,5..).
i.e. "AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD"

I can get them all using basic

```
dynamic resultList = result.facet_counts.facet_fields.Suggest.Children();
foreach (dynamic child in resultList)
{
   strings.Add(child.ToString());
}
```

But since all the dynamic fields are JVAlue and I have to use an index and add a condition, I wonder if there is a more elegant way (maybe linq?).
Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to deserialize the JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following from Linque.

```
resultList.Where((child, index) => (index) %2!=0);
```

I hope it will help u.

Answer (score 1):

One way to de-serialize your JSON is by using **Newtonsoft** *(instead of loops)*;

```
List<string> myList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(resultList);
```

And then my simple linq, you may filter your data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get it is using linq.

```
resultList.Where((obj, i) => (obj) %2!=0);
```